# TypeError: response.data is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having problems with promise response for a vForm PUT to UPDATE a model (backend in laravel).

The response code is 200 (OK, updated) and the model is updated, but I don't know why I'm having error with "response.data" in catch. There is no error and code in ".then()" is running correctly.

## EDIT

Service Update funciton (vue) using vForm.
    updateService(){
            this.$Progress.start();

```
        this.service.put('api/service/' + this.service.id)
        .then( function (response) {

          Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: response.data['Response']
          });

          this.$Progress.finish();

        })
        .catch( function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          Swal.fire("Error!", response.data['Response'], "warning");
          this.$Progress.fail();

        });

        this.$events.$emit('ServiceInform');
      },
```

Function in backend (laravel).

```
public function update(Request $request, Service $service)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'id_customers'      => 'required|int',
        'date'              => 'required|date',
        'id_technicians'    => 'required|int',
        'location'          => 'required|string',
        'details'           => 'required|string'
    ]);

    if ($request['id_technicians'] !== $service['id_technicians']) {
        $assignated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        $assigned_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    } else {
        $assignated_by = $service['assignated_by'];
        $assigned_date = $service['assigned_date'];
    }

    if ($request['id_technicians'] == 0) {
        $state = 'P';
    } else {
        $state = 'I';
    }

    $service->date              = $request['date'];
    $service->id_technicians    = $request['id_technicians'];
    $service->location          = $request['location'];
    $service->details           = $request['details'];
    $service->assigned_date     = $assigned_date;
    $service->assigned_by       = $assignated_by;
    $service->state             = $state;

    try {

        $service->save();

        return Response::json([
            'Response' => 'Servicio actualizado.'
        ], 201);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Response::json([
            'Response' => 'No se actualizó el servicio.'
        ], 422);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the result of you `console.log`?

Comment: You need to provide additional information. Are you using axios to make HTTP calls? Are you extracting `data` in `service` in success? You need to need to share the code for `this.service.put`. Also don't put images of your code into the question, paste the actual code into the question.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky the post is updated with new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line looks problematic to me:

```js
this.$Progress.finish();
```

It's trying to access `this` within the function passed to `then`. It seems unlikely that `this` will be referencing what you're expecting. You should be able to confirm with suitable console logging. My suspicion is that attempting to call `this.$Progress.finish()` will throw an error, triggering the `catch`.

Try using arrow functions for your `then` and `catch` callbacks instead.

Comment: Thanks!! thats was the error. Putting it out solve the problem.